# Using SimplePie with a custom element?

Tags: php, xml, simplepie

**I have a sample feed like so**

http://bingogs.bingosys.net/extGetRooms.php?NW=Plus&C=GBP

**Sample XML**

```
<ROOT xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql">
    <ROOM id="20" maxplayers="0" currentplayers="0" cm="" status="1" seconds="196" progressive="19.48" name="Tuppence Treats" cardvalue="0.02" jackpot="50.00" opentimes="2pm" roomtype="90" ticketGraphic="" lastWinner="" cardType="3"/>
    <ROOM id="39" maxplayers="0" currentplayers="0" cm="" status="1" seconds="1996" progressive="19.48" name="Fancy Free" cardvalue="0.00" jackpot="10.00" opentimes="Midday" roomtype="90" ticketGraphic="" lastWinner="" cardType="3"/>
</ROOT>
```

How would I go about accessing each ROOM's attributes such as maxplayers, lastWinner etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like SimpleXml from PHP (http://es.php.net/simplexml). There is a lot of librarys like that for parsing an xml document.